# ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away & conflict with max_allowed_packet

Tags: mysql

I wanted to import a sql dump

```
mysql -u username mydb < file.sql
```

And of course i get the classic `ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 1701: MySQL server has gone away` message. No big deal i know that i need to increase the packet size. So i edit the /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf file and add the line `max_allowed_packet=64M`. But when i try to start the mysql server i get an error.

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-01-21 16:27:47 CET; 15s ago
  Process: 9151 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 9112 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 27620 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 21 16:27:47 aleksandar-pc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan 21 16:27:47 aleksandar-pc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jan 21 16:27:47 aleksandar-pc systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jan 21 16:27:47 aleksandar-pc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 21 16:27:47 aleksandar-pc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

If i remove the code added for packets, the server can be started normally.
Can anyone help me with this, i really need to import this large db and don't know how to fix this mysql error.

Mysql verison: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64)
Linux: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: i advice you to move this question over to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ it's more DBA related..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i forgot this `[mysqld]` above:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=128M
```